# Clipped Imagery Larger File Size Than Input

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery

I have jp2 imagery over a larger area. For our consultant to use this imagery, they require the file size to be smaller. To reduce the file size, I am using ArcMap to clip the imagery to only the area of interest. But when I check the size of the output file (also jp2) they are bigger than the input!

Why is this and how might I get around it?

Comment: What format is your output image?  JPEG2000 is compressed so if your output is not then that would explain it.

Comment: @PolyGeo output is jp2 also

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  What precise tool and all parameter values did you use to perform the clip?

Comment: You are probably creating a less compressed output than the original.